# Pandas - Add single marker to boxplot using labelled index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe grouped by "Year", "Farm" and "Crop", and I'm using it to plot a boxplot showing "Yield t/ha" by "Crop" where each data point will be an individual "Farm average".

[image]

I want to add markers so that I can highlight where a specific farms data sits in this graph. Ultimately I plan to do this by filtering the dataset by the specific "Farm" and adding it to the plot. But at the moment I can't seem to do this even manually. I've tried various things including:

```
plt.plot('Linseed', 7, marker='^', markersize=10, markerfacecolor='green')
```

Which just does this:

[image]

It works if I pass the positional index value (e.g. 1) but that doesn't help me as this needs to be dynamic as the index values will change depending on what crops a "Farm" did and didn't grow.

The dataframe.index is a multiindex so I've tried passing a tuple for the x argument in .plot():

```
plt.plot((2022, 'Farm A', 'Linseed'), 7, marker='^', markersize=10, markerfacecolor='green')
```

but then I just get the error:

```
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (3,) and (1,)
```

How can I add single values to specific x-axis indices?

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, in your first suggestion:

```
plt.plot('Linseed', 7, marker='^', markersize=10, markerfacecolor='green')
```

Instead of passing the name 'Linseed', you need to pass the x-coordinate that corresponds to the 'Linseed' column. I don't see the code that created the boxplots, but probably the coordinate is 1.

Here is an example that replicates that:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dict_data = {x: np.random.randn(10) for x in range(3)}

plt.boxplot(dict_data.values());
plt.plot('test', 3, '^', c='blue')
plt.plot(1, 4, '^', c='green')
```

Best would be if you could specify the x-coordinate of your boxplots when you plot those, and then reuse it when plotting the individual triangle. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I did mention in the OP that it works if I pass in the positional index value (x-coordinate), but the problem is that it needs to be more dynamic as the order and list of crops can change depending on the farm. I suppose I could first filter the dataframe the only show the crops grown on the farm. But I was hoping to find a way where I could reference the x label itself.

Comment: Ah I see, you can do it post hoc but it's a bit hacky, using get_xticklabels(). I've edited my answer with another code block

Answer (score 0):

It's possible using `get_xticklabels()` as follows;

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dict_data = {f'data_{x}': np.random.randn(10) for x in range(3)}
df_data = pd.DataFrame(dict_data)

ax = plt.subplot(111)
df_data.boxplot()
xticklabels = ax.get_xticklabels()
xcoord_label = np.where([x._text == 'data_2' for x in xticklabels])[0]
ax.plot(xcoord_label + 1, 4, '^', c='green')
```